# Match transaction_start for post voided receipts with transaction_start from the original receipt

Tags: google-bigquery

Match post voided receipts with original receipts:

I have a `transaction` table that looks like this:

```
transaction_start        store_no        item_no        amount        post_voided
2021-02-28 08:00:00           001            101            45                  N
2021-02-28 08:00:00           001            105            25                  N
2021-02-28 08:00:00           001            109            40                  N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            101            45                  N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            105            25                  N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            109            40                  N
2021-03-01 10:02:00           002            101            45                  N
2021-03-01 10:02:00           002            105            25                  N
2021-03-01 10:02:00           002            109            40                  N
2021-03-01 10:04:00           001            101            45                  N
2021-03-01 10:05:00           002            103            35                  N
2021-03-01 10:05:00           002            135            20                  N
2021-03-01 10:08:00           001            140            2                   N
2021-03-01 10:11:00           001            101           -45                  Y
2021-03-01 10:11:00           001            105           -25                  Y
2021-03-01 10:11:00           001            109           -40                  Y
```

Each receipt/purchase is a combination of the `transaction_start` and `store_no`. Each receipt can have one or more `item_no` (and the respective price given by the `amount` variable). If the receipt has two or more items, the `transaction_start` and `store_no` values are repeated. So in the table above, a total of 7 receipts can be observed: receipt 1 is given by `transaction_start` = '2021-02-28 08:00:00' and `store_no` = '001', and contains the following items: 101, 105 and 109; receipt 2 by `transaction_start` = '2021-03-01 10:00:00' and `store_no` = '001', containing the following items: 101, 105 and 109, and so on.

The last receipt (`transaction_start` = '2021-03-01 10:11:00' and `store_no` = '001') is a post voided of the second receipt (`transaction_start` = '2021-03-01 10:00:00' and `store_no` = '001'). The post voided indication is given by the column and value `post_voided` = 'Y'.

My goal is to change the `transaction_start` for the `post_voided` = 'Y' receipts for the original `transaction_start` datetime. By original receipt, it is meant that all `item_no` and (negative) `amount` from the post voided receipt (i.e. `post_voided` = 'Y') must match with the closest (i.e. equal or lower) `transaction_start`, `store_no` receipt contaitning the same `item_no`, (positive) `amount` and not post voided (o.e. `post_voided` = 'N').

Desired output:

```
transaction_start        store_no        item_no        amount        post_voided
2021-02-28 08:00:00           001            101            45                  N
2021-02-28 08:00:00           001            105            25                  N
2021-02-28 08:00:00           001            109            40                  N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            101            45                  N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            105            25                  N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            109            40                  N
2021-03-01 10:02:00           002            101            45                  N
2021-03-01 10:02:00           002            105            25                  N
2021-03-01 10:02:00           002            109            40                  N
2021-03-01 10:04:00           001            101            45                  N
2021-03-01 10:05:00           002            103            35                  N
2021-03-01 10:05:00           002            135            20                  N
2021-03-01 10:08:00           001            140            2                   N
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            101           -45                  Y
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            105           -25                  Y
2021-03-01 10:00:00           001            109           -40                  Y
```

Here a link of the table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06afe841d89c4ecbf600436433cd1c5d

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
with receipts as (
  select transaction_start, store_no, post_voided, 
    format('%t', array_agg(struct(item_no, abs(amount) as amount) order by item_no)) receipt_hash
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by transaction_start, store_no, post_voided
), last_receipts as ( 
  select any_value(y).*, 
    max(n.transaction_start) last_transaction_start,
  from receipts y
  join receipts n
  on y.transaction_start >= n.transaction_start
  and y.store_no = n.store_no
  and y.receipt_hash = n.receipt_hash
  where y.post_voided = 'Y' and n.post_voided = 'N'
  group by format('%t', y)
)
select a.* 
  replace(if(a.post_voided = 'N', transaction_start, last_transaction_start) as transaction_start)
from `project.dataset.table` a
left join last_receipts
using(transaction_start, store_no)
```

if applied to sample in question - output is.

[image]